# What does "show up with" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "Sometimes Western manufacturers have to use out-of-date technology (from 1985) in building C919 for intellectual property reasons"?

"Basically, they're telling them they have no intellectual property protection," said Aboulafia. "This means you have Western manufacturers sometimes **showing up with** the 'latest and best' from 1985."

Source: http://www.cnbc.com/2017/05/08/chinas-new-passenger-jet-is-not-seen-as-an-immediate-threat-to-boeing-airbus.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sentence

> This means you have Western manufacturers sometimes **showing up with** the 'latest and best' from 1985,

"**showing up with**" means that the western manufacturers **expose**/**reveal**/**offer**/**come up with** obsolete technology because they are offered no intellectual property rights. 'Latest and best' from 1985 refers to the technology which was considered modern/advanced in 1985 but is obsolete as of now.

> Partnering with Western equipment manufacturers under preconditions such as a requirement of Chinese manufacturing will add risk and ultimately not bring the most current technology, due to intellectual property concerns

The above paragraph elucidates that western companies shy away from offering the latest tech due to IP concerns.